# React: how can I open a single modal when clicking on a card

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

I'm working on a personal project with the following requisites:

- Consult an API which provides a list of objects with the following properties: {_id: String, title: String, url: String}
- Render a grid of cards. Each card should have an h1 tag containing the title property.
- When the user clicks on a card, a modal should open.
- The modal should contain an iframe with an empty src attribute.
- If the modal is open, the iframe should contain the URL property of the card as its src.
- When the modal is closed, the iframe src must be set empty.

So far, I can render each card. The problem is, when I click on one, the web application renders a modal for every card (it should open only the modal of that specific card).

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react'

// allCards is a function that asks an API for data.
import { allCards } from '../functions/functions'


const Cards = () => {

  const [cards, setCards] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    allCards(setCards)
    
  }, [])

  const [cardModalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
  
  function openCardModal() {
    setModalIsOpen(true);
  }

  function closeModalHandler() {
    setModalIsOpen(false);
  }
  
  return (
    <main>
      
      {cards !== null ? (
        cards.map(card => (
          
          <div key={card._id} className='card-preview' onClick={() => {
            console.log(`clicked on card ${card._id}`)
            openCardModal()
          }}>
            <h2 className='card-title'>{card.cardTitle}</h2>
          </div>
          ))) : ('No cards found')}

{ newsModalIsOpen &&            
  
cards.map(card => (
  <div className='cardmodalcontainer'  onClick={closeModalHandler}>
      <div className='modal-container'>
        <iframe src={cardModalIsOpen ? card.url : ''} frameBorder="0" className='cardmodal'>
        </iframe>
      </div>
  </div>
))

}

    </main>
    )}

export default Cards
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this problem? I would greatly appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a Cards Parent Component and a CardView child Component and pass the index of the card as props like so :

```
function Cards() {
  //set cards to an empty array
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([])
  //set each card to an individual object
  const [card, setCard] = useState({})
  const [showCardView, setShowCardView] = useState(false)


  const handleCard = (card) => {
    setCard(card)
    setShowCardView(true)
    ...other logic here
  }

  return(
    <>
      {
      cards.map((card, index) => {
        return (
          // pass the card at index clicked to a handler function 
          <div key={index} onClick={() => handleCard(card)}>
            ... whatever here
          </div>
        ) 
      })
      }
      // pass the card object and the updater function as props from state
      {showCardView ? <CardView card={card} setShowCardView={setShowCardView}/> : null}
    </>
  )
}

function CardView(props) {
  return (
    <>
      access with props
      <span onclick={props.setShowCardView(false)}></span>
      <h2>{props.card.cardTitle}</h2>
      ... whatever here
    </>
  )
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, Randall! It works great. I'm very happy with the results.

Comment: Awesome Glad to hear it! :)